# CodeIgniter pagination with search doesn't show second page

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I am trying to see why my pagination with search keeps reverting to its default state when I go to page 2.

I've taken a look at some examples that have said to put my search terms in session data so that the search could be retained but so far I have had no luck in making this work. My code partially comes from this site : https://dzone.com/articles/how-paginate-search-results 
and I am not sure how correct that method is.

This is what I have so far

Controller :

```
public function date_function(){
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');
    $date_start = $this->table_DateStartHandler($this->input->post('date_start'));
    $date_end = $this->table_DateEndHandler($this->input->post('dateend'));
    $current_status = $this->table_StatusHandler($this->input->post('current_status'));

    $config['base_url'] = base_url('/Report/date_function');
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->ControlModel->count_Date($date_start,$date_end,$current_status);
    $config['per_page'] = 40;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 4;
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
    $config['prev_link'] = '&lt;';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>'; 
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['next_link'] = '&gt;';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="current"><a href="#">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $config['first_link'] = '&lt;&lt;';
    $config['last_link'] = '&gt;&gt;';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $page = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 0;
    $message['datatable'] = $this->ControlModel->getSubmissions_Date($config["per_page"], $page,$date_start,$date_end,$current_status);

    $message['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

    $message['counter'] = $config['total_rows'];

    //$message['datatable'] = $this->ControlModel->getSubmissions();
    $message['message'] = '';
    $this->load->view('control_report',$message);
}
```

The functions where I check if there is userdata in the session

```
public function table_StatusHandler($current_status){
    if($current_status){
        $this->session->set_userdata('current_status', $current_status);
        return $current_status;
    }elseif($this->session->set_userdata('current_status')){
        $current_status = $this->session->userdata('current_status');
        return $current_status;
    }else{
        $current_status = "";
        return $current_status;
    }
}

public function table_DateStartHandler($date_start){
    if($date_start){
        $this->session->set_userdata('date_start', $date_start);
        return $date_start;
    }elseif($this->session->set_userdata('date_start')){
        $date_start = $this->session->userdata('date_start');
        return $date_start;
    }else{
        $date_start = "";
        return $date_start;
    }
}

public function table_DateEndHandler($date_end){
    if($date_end){
        $this->session->set_userdata('date_end', $date_end);
        return $date_end;
    }elseif($this->session->set_userdata('date_end')){
        $date_end = $this->session->userdata('date_end');
        return $date_end;
    }else{
        $date_end = "";
        return $date_end;
    }
}
```

Hope someone can help
Thank you

Comment: Hey, you need to ```POST``` your ```searchString``` on every pagination link click by using jQuery.

Comment: huh? must I use jquery? I'd like to try to stick to php as much as I can

Comment: well you need just small piece of code (jQuery). If you can manage the click of page number leads to submit the form then you can do it.

Comment: is there an example of how this is done? I'm a little confused

Answer (score 0):

Give id to your form as `searchList`. And then try this code by pasting in your view

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var baseURL = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>';
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('ul.pagination li a').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();            
            var link = jQuery(this).get(0).href;            
            var value = link.substring(link.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            jQuery("#searchList").attr("action", baseURL + "Report/date_function/" + value);
            jQuery("#searchList").submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

In your controller function :

```
public function date_function(){
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');
    $date_start = $this->table_DateStartHandler($this->input->post('date_start'));
    $date_end = $this->table_DateEndHandler($this->input->post('dateend'));
    $current_status = $this->table_StatusHandler($this->input->post('current_status'));

    // You Pagination Code


    $message["date_start"] = $this->input->post('date_start');
    $message["dateend"] = $this->input->post('dateend');
    $message["current_status"] = $this->input->post('current_status');

    $this->load->view('control_report',$message);
}
```

Those three parameters I sent in array `$message`, assign them back to you input controls when you load the view.

Comment: I changed the answer, please take a look, tell me if any error you got.

Comment: Ill try this and have a look

Comment: Sorry is there any way this solution can be a pure php one?

Comment: Try GET request instead of POST.